# Sitecore Multisite using querystring instead of domain/subdomain?

Tags: sitecore

Is there a way to setup mulitple sites to run using querystrings rather than domains/subdomains?

I am developing a site that has a Global site and multiple country specific sites (exact list of countries to be confirmed later). For development I have a Global and a Local site created and running on a temporary subdomain. If this works correctly we may run the entire application this way rather than on separate domains (similar to how apple.com appears to work)

I have successfully got the sites running locally as:

```
global.domain.com
a.domain.com
b.domain.com
```

but would like them to be able to run as:

```
www.domain.com/global
www.domain.com/a
www.domain.com/b
```

We will be implementing multiple languages on certain country sites aswell so locale will need to remain independant.

Could this be done using some sort of URL mapping rather than multiple sites or something? Where can I find information about URL mapping?

Comment: A query string would be `www.domain.com?site=global` - you're after a (virtual) subfolder

Comment: Are you looking for multi-site or multi-language for the same site?

Comment: It will be multiple sites, each one the potential to have multiple languages.

Comment: I realised its not really a querystring solution I'm looking for but more of a path

Answer (score 1):

There are settings for using virtual folders (see web.config under sites node)

```
virtualFolder: The prefix to match for incoming URL's.
                             This value will be removed from the URL and the remainder will be treated as the item path.
```

How that works in practice I'm not sure - it's on a domain by domain basis, and all your sites will be operating from the same domain.

But I think you might want to reconsider your approach. Sub domains have several advantages. They're simple to configure in the web.config (just add a domain and point it at the right bit of the content tree).
They simplify search engine optimisation - e.g. telling google to target a specific subdomain to a geographical area in Google webmaster tools.
They're simple for visitors to understand.

Bear in mind that if you're going to use multiple languages per site then you will probably want to keep the language parameter in the URL as part of the (virtual) filepath (e.g. www.mysite.com/en-GB/products)

If you use both language and locale in the URL in that way you end up with something like www.mysite.com/UK/en-GB/products

Comment: Yes, this does sound like it would provide the solution I'm after however when I try to setup the virtualFolder, when trying to browse to the site using that folder I just get: Server Error in '/' Application.
Value cannot be null.
Parameter name: virtualPath Any idea on where I might find more info on this problem?

Comment: Sorry, I've no experience with trying this. As I say, I think subdomains are probably preferable - they're certainly tried and tested.